# Converting from Swift 2.3 to 3.0

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, realm

I'm trying to migrate my Swift project from Swift 2.3 to Swift 3.0. I'm using the Realm framework for data storage, and it's giving me a headache!

I have tried several times now, and i have manually migrated from Swift 2.2 to Swift 2.3.

But after i used the build in migration assistent, i'm getting the following error.

[image]

I can't see which binaries causing the issue this time, but earlier it came up with Realm and RealmSwift framework. I have upgraded the Realm pods to version 1.1.

I have tried Clean Build my folder several times, and i have deleted everthing inside DerivedData, but the same issue still persist.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried installing `Realm` for `Swift 3`?

Comment: Hi @EmilDavid. I got the following text in my Podfile:   pod 'Realm', git: 'https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa.git', branch: 'master', submodules: true
  pod 'RealmSwift', git: 'https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa.git', branch: 'master', submodules: true. So i guess i have tried it :)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Podfile, add `use_frameworks!` and `pod 'RealmSwift'` to your main and test targets. Paste the following at the bottom of your Podfile updating the Swift version to 3.0:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
    end
  end
end
```

Source: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#installation

Credit for this goes to [jpsim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/373262/jpsim).

Comment: Realm on CocoaPods supports Swift 2.2, 2.3 and 3.0. Installation instructions can be found here: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#installation

Comment: The podspec for the `Realm` pod (Realm Objective-C) claims support for iOS 7, which is correct, but the `RealmSwift` podspec (Realm Swift), only supports iOS 8 and up.

Comment: You are right, I did not know that. Since he already accepted my answer, I updated it.

Comment: Thanks for answering!